# Braintree PHP Library (3.8.0) Error Handling

Tags: php, braintree

The **PHP** library returns result objects from most of the **API** calls. What is the official way of distinguishing between a validation error and a transaction error?

The *Braintree docs* seem to suggest using `sizeof($result->errors) > 0` to determine if validation errors have occurred. But this is also > 0 when a transaction error has occurred.

The only other way I can think of is somehow determining whether the transaction object exists within the `$result` object, a bit of a hack, and then viewing the status within the transaction object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

You are correct that the suggested way to check for transaction errors is to see if there is a transaction object present. Here is a snippet of code illustrating appropriate error handling for a `Braintree\Transaction::sale` call.

```
if ($result->success){
    $transaction = $result->transaction;
} elseif (!is_null($result->transaction)){
    $transaction = $result->transaction;
    $_SESSION["errors"] = "Transaction status - " . $result->transaction->status;
} else {
    $errorString = "";

    foreach($result->errors->deepAll() as $error) {
        $errorString .= $error->code . "-" . $error->message . "\n";
    }

    $_SESSION["errors"] = $errorString;
}
```

Comment: It is the same for .Net, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. Error handling is [similar](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_aspnet_example/blob/7a899d77452c7c5647e196ab60f38ca7528c13ec/BraintreeASPExample/Controllers/CheckoutsController.cs#L54-L73)

Comment: Hi @pblesi , I have implemented something similar to your solution. But error messages are not **user friendly**. For ex. `paymentMethodNonce does not contain a valid payment instrument type.` , `Credit card must include number, paymentMethodNonce, or venmoSdkPaymentMethodCode` (trying to submit empty CC no.)

Is there a better general message I can show? Dealing with each **error code** does not seem to be a good solution either.